# Implementing Gravity Model in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder

I need to find suitable sites for solar plant in rural area of Afghanistan and then narrow down the selected sites according to people demands using gravity model. I have found the selected sites (around 30 sites) with GIS techniques but for minimizing the selected site to people demand with gravity model I have problem.

Is there any one to help me in the issues. I also need the methodology as well (ModelBuilder in ArcGIS).

Comment: What problem do you have?

Comment: Actually, I have found about 30 site which are suitable for solar farm plant according to solar radiation, slope, aspect and other economic, topographic and climate factors in rural area of four provinces of Afghanistan. But now I want to use gravity model to narrow down( find most suitable sites between 30 sites), according to population density in villages and people demand. I have an output of optimum sites with 30 points applying gravity model in the case to minimize these sites to 4 or five is my concern point.

Answer (score 2):

Other than you wanting to implement a graph model in ArcGIS, it is unclear what you are after or what you problem is. It is your responsibility to figure out the "methodology" and the relevant theory behind your question. Please provide some clarification and specifics otherwise you question is bound to be down-voted and closed. Please take the [site tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how to formulate a good question.

Other than digging into code, you have very few options here. Several years ago (2006) David Theobald developed the [ArcGIS FunnConn toolbox](http://conservationcorridor.org/corridor-toolbox/programs-and-tools/funconn/), written in Python. This code is very much depreciated and would need a complete rewrite but, it is a place to start. He structured the code in a way that implementing a gravity model would be possible. I would search around to see if anybody has implemented a gravity model in Python and then port it to ArcGIS. Otherwise, graph libraries written for other purposes, such as [pgmpy](https://github.com/pgmpy/pgmpy), could be a starting point for code but, you would still need to code the actual graph model itself.

It is not as simple as building a graph, for the gravity form, you have to specify a log transformed matrix regression with multiple intercepts. Recent literature also indicates that competing models should be evaluated using REMEL (maximum likelihood) and not AIC.

I have an R package "[GeNetIt](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GeNetIt/index.html)", available on CRAN, that implements the gravity model form and has several function to assist in building spatial graphs and the model matrix, representing from-to data structure, suitable for specifying the model. It is in a singly constrained form but, one could specify a double constrained however, it would be questionable what this would mean and our predict function would not work for estimating a doubly constrained model. We solve the graph model using a mixed effects regression.

Comment: Actually, I have found about 30 site which are suitable for solar farm plant according to solar radiation, slope, aspect and other economic, topographic and climate factors in rural area of four provinces of Afghanistan. But now I want to use gravity model to narrow down( find most suitable sites between 30 sites), according to population density in villages and people demand. I have an output of optimum sites with 30 points applying gravity model in the case to minimize these sites to 4 or five is my concern point.

Comment: Following code is downloaded from Esri Website which is related to gravity mode. but I don't know much about python.